# week_field gives wrong week after serialization and deserialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, serialization

I'm using the week_field helper to generate a week picker in a form. When I choose a week and submit, my controller gets the correct serialized week (e.g. '2014-W03') which I can turn into a date object. That all works, but when the date is serialized again it is always decremented by 1 (e.g. it'll be '2014-W02'). I looked at the [source code for the week_field helper](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/week_field.rb) and it serializes as

```
  def format_date(value)
    value.try(:strftime, "%Y-W%W")
  end
```

but this doesn't seem to be the encoding when the date is parsed. Furthermore, parsing and then serializing a date yeilded this wonky result:

```
irb > Date.parse('2014-W03').strftime('%Y-W%W')
 => "2014-W02"
```

Any ideas as to what's going on here or how I can do this in a way that makes sense? I'd hate to have an extra +1 on the week number or change the `week_field` `format_date` definition if there's a cleaner route.

Comment: I submitted a PR to rails to fix this: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22190

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime :

```
%W - Week number of the year.  The week starts with Monday.  (00..53)
```

It seems you have the good old - start with 0 or start with 1 - problem. Strftime will start counting weeks with 0.

But maybe %V is the right thing for you:

ISO 8601 week-based year and week number:

The week 1 of YYYY starts with a Monday and includes YYYY-01-04.
The days in the year before the first week are in the last week of
the previous year.

```
%G - The week-based year
%g - The last 2 digits of the week-based year (00..99)
%V - Week number of the week-based year (01..53)
```

Comment: I'm afraid you're correct. I had to increment the week number when the time came to serialize the week number. It's just odd that using two methods provided/used by rails would inconsistent results like this. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, indeed it's odd. Usually you find this kind of inconsistency in PHP, or that sort; so I had another look and modified my answer.